# Incorrect syntax in query which is loading data into excel file

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I have I query  which is writing in excel file.

Query looks like this

```
EXEC sp_makewebtask @outputfile = 'e:\Testing.xls',
   @query = '  SELECT top 10 *
               FROM [myDB].[dbo].[TOTALS_DAY]
               WHERE [START_DATETIME] < '20140501'', 
   @FixedFont=0, 
   @lastupdated=0, 
   @resultstitle = 'Testing details'
```

If I comment out where clause its generated, however I have to use date and when I specify  date its throwing me error.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '20140501'.

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written 2 '', try this:

### Edit

```
DECLARE  @date DATETIME 
set @date = '20140501'
EXEC sp_makewebtask @outputfile = 'e:\Testing.xls',
 @query = '  SELECT top 10 *
   FROM [myDB].[dbo].[TOTALS_DAY]
   where [START_DATETIME] < @date, 
   @FixedFont=0, 
   @lastupdated=0, 
   @resultstitle='Testing details'
```

i hope this helps

Comment: i have to have additional  `'` after  date, that is the problem

Comment: Maybe declaring a @date variable with your date, then comparing agains this variable

Comment: If you set a `DATETIME` value, you should use the **proper** ISO-8601 format which is `YYYYMMDD` (**without** any dashes!) to be absolutely independent of language settings. The version with the dashes **can fail** depending on your language settings. So use `set @date = '20140501'` instead of what you have

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have unintentionally matched quotes. Since you are surrounding you SQL statement in single quotes, then query is interpreted as

```
'  SELECT top 10 *
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[TOTALS_DAY]
where [START_DATETIME] < '
```

Which means nothing. Since the date is supposed to be in single quotes, is it possible to put your value for `@query` in double quotes? Like this:

```
EXEC sp_makewebtask @outputfile = 'e:\Testing.xls',
 @query = "  SELECT top 10 *
   FROM [myDB].[dbo].[TOTALS_DAY]
   where [START_DATETIME] < '20140501'", 
   @FixedFont=0, 
   @lastupdated=0, 
   @resultstitle='Testing details'
```

Comment: it doesn't like double quoits :(

Answer (score 1):

There is and extra single quote try:

```
EXEC sp_makewebtask @outputfile = 'e:\Testing.xls',
 @query = '  SELECT top 10 *
   FROM [myDB].[dbo].[TOTALS_DAY]
   where [START_DATETIME] < '20140501', 
   @FixedFont=0, 
   @lastupdated=0, 
   @resultstitle='Testing details'
```

Comment: I have to have it  because it closing select  statement  if i delete it  its throwing `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '20140501'.` Error

Answer (score 0):

i did it different  way because declaration of variable with datetime format  didnt work for me i find way around  and did it  like this

`EXEC sp_makewebtask
 @outputfile = 'e:\VT_TOTALS_DAY_en_US.xls',
 @query = 'SELECT  * from
   FROM [myDB].[dbo].[TOTALS_DAY]
   where [START_DATETIME] <  DATEADD(DAY,  -20, GETDATE())', 
   @lastupdated=0, 
   @resultstitle='Testing details'`

have to use `DATEADD(DAY,  -20, GETDATE())` to get 2014-05-01